# Access an application using keycloak authentication on a local server from a remote PC using a VPN service

Tags: angular, keycloak

I have a server that is running locally with keycloak running as a docker container. I have another application running on the same server that uses keycloak for login (The application redirects to the keycloak URL for login). Now I have configured a VPN service that gives me the possibility to access this application on a remote PC via IP (not the local server IP but an IP configured with the VPN service). The issue now is that when i launch this application from the remote PC (with the IP configured in the VPN service), the application then tries to redirect to the keycloak service which is running on the local server (with the local server IP) and since the remote PC cannot access the local IP of the server,  the process fails. Is there any implementation like this or any other way I can get this to work? (Also I still want to be able to access the application locally on the server via the local server IP)
The application in question is developed with Angular
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the application to access keycloak using the VPN IP.